# Strange UITableViewCell shadow behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, calayer, shadow

I am trying to add shadow to single UITableViewCell. I am using this code in my custom cell subclass:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    layer.masksToBounds = false
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.9
    layer.shadowRadius = 10
    layer.shadowPath = CGPath(rect: bounds, transform: nil)
}
```

But the shadow usually appears only on bottom/top edge of the cell and it changes during scrolling.

[image: This is what it does]

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Your shadow path must be within you cell bounds. You're setting `shadowRadius` to 10 but the shadow path is your cell.bounds, then the shadow goes beyond your cell bounds,  hence you're getting this behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't see the shadow because the cell above/below is higher in the view-hierarchy depending on whether it was dequeued before or after your custom cell. Check out the View-Hierarchy-Debugger in Xcode to spot the issue.

You have a couple of possible solutions but I will outline 2 of them here:

1. You can use `bringSubviewToFront` in your `tableView` to make sure your custom cell is always on top.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if cell.isKind(of: MyCustomShadowCell.self) {
        tableView.bringSubviewToFront(cell)
    }
}
```

2. Another solution would be to set the `layer.zPosition` of the cell to something high, so that it's always on top. Imo that's a bit hack-ish but if you wanna try: `layer.zPosition = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude`.

Comment: Thank you very much :) , `bringSubviewToFront` solved my problem. I've strugged with that for few hours.

Answer (score 0):

`layoutSubviews()` isn't an appropriate place for such UI setup.
Since you need to add shadow only to some specific cell, apply or remove it when you fill the cell with data. Don't forget to remove unnecessary shadows, otherwise, when the cell is reused, the shadow will stay.

Comment: I tried to add shadow when filling the cell with data as you say. The behavior was the same. Other cells have different class and ReuseIdentifier, I need shadow only for this specific one. I tried clearing the shadow in prepareForReuse()

Answer (score 0):

Your shadow must be contained within your cell bounds. What is happening is your shadow actually goes beyond your cell bounds, and when cell is reused and placed in the table view the next cell covers your shadow. When you scroll up and down the cells are reused again in different order and depending on that your shadow might appear or not.

Try changing this line of code

```
layer.shadowPath = CGPath(rect: bounds, transform: nil)
```

to this

```
layer.shadowPath = CGPath(rect: .init(x: 0,
                                  y: 10,
                                  width: contentView.bounds.width,
                                  height: contentView.bounds.height - 20),
                      transform: nil)
```

This will place your shadow inside the bounds, but I don't think it will look as good as my next suggestion.

My second suggestion to you, is to create another parent view to hold your cell subviews. Then add this as subview of your cell's `contentView` and apply the shadow to the parent view layer instead of the cell's `contentView`. Make sure parent view had a padding of 10 from top and bottom and you will achieve what you want.